# How display a button after a typerwriter effects finish?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use typewritter effect in order to write a text line then display a button when the animation stops.

styles.css:

```
.welcome-msg {
    overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
    border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
    letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
    animation: 
      typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
      blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  }


  /* The typing effect */
  @keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width: 100% }
  }

  /* The typewriter cursor effect */
  @keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: orange; }
  }
```

UserMenu.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import AppBar from "../../common/AppBar";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import './styles.css';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";


const UserMenu = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleLogout = () => {
    history.push('/')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar label="user" handleLogout={handleLogout} />
      <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center" justify="center" style={{ height: "50vh" }}>
        <Grid item>
          <h1 className="welcome-msg">Welcome to user homepage</h1>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">Create</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}
export default UserMenu;
```

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `onAnimationEnd`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event):

> The **animationend** event is fired when a CSS Animation has completed. If
>   the animation aborts before reaching completion, such as if the
>   element is removed from the DOM or the animation is removed from the
>   element, the animationend event is not fired.

```js
 <h1
   onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd) 
  className="welcome-msg">Welcome to user homepage
</h1>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-raman-8ltmk)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.

Comment: @Slim Of course. I added a demo link at the end of my answer in case you want to see it in action.

Comment: Thank you so much.